# Static initialization order in valgrind

Tags: valgrind

I want to test for units in a c++ program that have the static initialization order fiasco problem. Under ASAN as far as I know there is the check_initialization_order flag that does this.

Is there an equivalent in Valgrind?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing that I'm aware of.

If you run your application under Valgrind it should detect uses of uninitialized memory. It's then up to you to figure out the exact cause and solutions.